# How to limit customers buy one product with woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want that customer can purchase only one product from woo commerce whenever they came back to shop page they will be redirected to my account page.

```
  <?php
/**
 * Loop Add to Cart
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.1.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

global $product;
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

if ( wc_customer_bought_product( $current_user->user_email, $current_user->ID, $product->id)) {
    $redirect = $myaccount;
}
```

i am using the following code placed in loop folder but its not working.

i want that user can purchase product once in lifetime 
note - its not about purchasing one product at one time
its like if someone purchased the product Then he/she will never able to purchase any other product.

Comment: Check this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-max-quantity/)

Comment: Can you check my answer and let me know if that worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

The `loop/add-to-cart.php` template creates a link. Your template only lists some variables (where are `$redirect` and `$myaccount` defined?) and does not create a link so it doesn't *do* anything.

A better solution would be to filter the link that is created in the `loop/add-to-cart.php` template via the `woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link` filter. This way if the item hasn't been purchased you can leave the regular link in tact.

Add the following to your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'so_add_to_cart_link', 10, 2 );
function so_add_to_cart_link( $link, $product ){

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    if ( wc_customer_bought_product( $current_user->user_email, $current_user->ID, $product->id)) {
        $link = sprintf( '<a href="%s" rel="nofollow" class="button product_type_%s">%s</a>',
            esc_url( get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ) ) ),
            esc_attr( $product->product_type ),
            __( 'View my account', 'theme-text-domain' ),
        ),
    }

    return $link;
}
```

Note that the above hasn't been tested, so be wary of typos.

Comment: Thanks for reply but i want that user can purchase product once in lifetime 
note - its not about purchasing one product at one time
its like if someone purchased the product Then he/she will never able to purchase any other product.

Comment: So instead of `wc_customer_bought_product` you need to write a custom function that determines if the customer had ever purchased anything. The rest still applies.

Comment: i am not good in coding so can you please share  the code 
thanks

Comment: if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_order_details_table' ) ) {
$link = sprintf( '<a href="%s" rel="nofollow" class="button product_type_%s">%s</a>',
            esc_url( get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ) ) ),
            esc_attr( $product->product_type ),
            __( 'View my account', 'theme-text-domain' ),
        ),
  return $link;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Open your theme **functions.php**, and put below code at the end.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'woo_custom_add_to_cart' );

function woo_custom_add_to_cart( $cart_item_data ) {
global $woocommerce;
$woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();

return $cart_item_data;
}
```

Now you can test by adding new product to your existing cart with items, see whether it will added the latest product only and remove all previous products in the cart.

Comment: Thanks for reply but i want that user can purchase product once in lifetime 
note - its not about purchasing one product at one time
its like if someone purchased the product Then he/she will never able to purchase any other product.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can limit the purchase to 1 product in your entire life in the store. I'm not sure about the quantity allowed for that product for the first time so I'll keep it variable in the below code.

**Task 1: Allow to purchase 1 product at a time.**
This can be simply achieved by the standard Woocommerce settings:

[image: Sold individually settings]

**Task 2: Allow users to buy a product only once in their entire lifetime.**

This will ensure that any user can purchase any product from your store only once and then can't buy any other product

This code will go in your functions.php file of the child theme or you can use any snippets plugin to do so.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'remove_product_from_cart_redirect', 999);
function remove_product_from_cart_redirect() {
    global $woocommerce;

    //Only use this code if the user is logged in
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $userId = get_current_user_id(); 
        // Get the TOTAL number of orders for the User
        $totalOrders = wc_get_customer_order_count( $userId );

       // Get CANCELLED orders for customer
       $args = array(
            'customer_id' => $userId,
            'post_status' => 'cancelled',
            'post_type' => 'shop_order',
            'return' => 'ids',
        );
        $cancelledOrders = count( wc_get_orders( $args ) );

        //all orders except cancelled ones
        $totalNotCancelled = $totalOrders - $cancelledOrders;

        if ($totalNotCancelled > 1) { //if already purchased anything on the store.
            //empty the cart
            WC()->cart->empty_cart( true );
            //Optionally displaying a notice for the removed item:
            wc_add_notice( __( 'We have removed the product from your cart.', 'woocommerce' ), 'notice' );
         
            //Redirect to a my-account page
            wp_redirect( get_permalink(get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id')));
            
        }
    }
}
```

**Note: Above code will not work with Ajax add to cart so please turn that off from Woocommerce settings here:**

[image: Turn off ajax add to cart]